# Divide by Zero Anomaly in PHP

Tags: php, divide-by-zero

[image: Google Chrome 500 Error]

Okay, so I was playing around with the idea of a stack overflow loop. I entered the following code and got a cute little image in Google Chrome (their answer for a 500 internal error which is NOT helpful by the way Google!). This was as expected and on purpose.

**Code Set #2**

```
<?php
    for($x=-1;$x<=3;$x++){
     echo $x/0.">";
    }
?>
```

By checking the headers I found:

```
http://server.domain/overflow.php

GET /overflow.php HTTP/1.1
Host: server.domain
User-Agent: Browser
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0

HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error
Date: Thu, 22 Aug 2013 21:51:30 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.3
Content-Length: 0
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

I arrived at the above code because I was actually wondering about dividing by zero and how PHP handled it. I wrote the code below to try and trigger the result, but didn't get what I was expecting. The problem is rather than getting a `500 internal server error` from the following code, I get something else... a `NULL` where I would expect the server to throw the error.

**Code Set #1**

```
<?php
    for($x=-1;$x<=3;$x++){
     echo $x/$x.">";
    }
?>
```

**Output**

```
1>>1>1>1>
```

### Question

Why isn't the first bit of code causing a 500 internal server error since I'm dividing by zero? `1/1=1`,`1/0=500 Error`,`0/0=Null`

Comment: Check your server logs. When you get server errors you will find them there.

Comment: I saw the 500 error from the second code set. I was expecting it from the first, but only got a NULL.

Comment: PHP is nice enough to not let the world end and throw a nice warning for you instead. Good guy PHP.

Comment: well, you might also be interested to learn about operator precedence http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about enabling error reporting.

Comment: `ini_set('display_errors',1);  error_reporting(E_ALL);` works wonders

Comment: @AmalMurali Yeah, I had allow override disabled in the config. So that didn't work. Thought `display_errors` was enabled.

Comment: This is interesting. You pretend that 
    0 / 0 = null
And
    1 / 0 => division by zero

I will test this tomorrow.

Comment: @LorenzMeyer I wasn't pretending, just looking at the output with the assumption that `display_errors` was on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get an error with the first version, because you have a syntax error. PHP treats the dot in `0.` as a decimal point, not a concatenation operator. The correct code would be either:

```
($x/0) . ">"; // This version is my preference
```

Or:

```
$x/0. . ">";
```

Comment: or separate the expressions just with a comma. oh right PHP already tells you that in the error message. lol.

Comment: @hakre That would also work for the OP, because echo can accept multiple arguments, but in the general case of string concatenation with a numerical literal it may not, so I left it out.

Answer (score 3):

You should get

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '">"' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in /your_file.php on line 3
```

Changing your code to

```
<?php
    for($x=-1;$x<=3;$x++){
     echo $x/0;
     echo ">";
    }
?>
```

will get you

```
Warning: Division by zero in /your_file.php on line 3
>
Warning: Division by zero in /your_file.php on line 3
>
Warning: Division by zero in /your_file.php on line 3
>
Warning: Division by zero in /your_file.php on line 3
>
Warning: Division by zero in /your_file.php on line 3
>
```